# ggplot legend order with multiple geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", 
                              "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01")),
             col2 = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2), levels = c("C", "A", "B")),
             col3 = c(8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 5))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   col1       col2   col3
#>   <date>     <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 2020-01-01 A         8
#> 2 2020-01-01 B         3
#> 3 2020-01-01 C         2
#> 4 2020-02-01 A         9
#> 5 2020-02-01 B         1
#> 6 2020-02-01 C         5

levels(df$col2)
#> [1] "C" "A" "B"
```

I've created the data frame `df` with `col2` factored as shown above. I think that this ordering of factors determines the default ordering of ggplot legend entries, but that's not the case as shown below.

```
ggplot(df, aes(col1, col3, fill = col2)) + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 != "C"), 
           position = "dodge", 
           color = "black") + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 == "C"), 
           width = 15,
           color = "black") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend"))
```

[image: ggplot legend reorder with multiple geoms]

I'm going to speculate that the `col2` level ordering (*#> [1] "C" "A" "B"*) is not respected in ggplot's legend ordering because there are multiple geoms in my code. Is this correct? How do I get the legend entries to appear in the following order?

1. C
2. A
3. B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the limits on a colour scale:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", 
                              "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01")),
             col2 = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2), levels = c("C", "A", "B")),
             col3 = c(8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 5))

ggplot(df, aes(col1, col3, fill = col2)) + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 != "C"), 
           position = "dodge", 
           color = "black") + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 == "C"), 
           width = 15,
           color = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend",
                      limits = c("C", "A", "B"))
```

[image]

Alternatively you can set `drop = FALSE` in the scale, so it doesn't drop unused levels between layers:

```
ggplot(df, aes(col1, col3, fill = col2)) + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 != "C"), 
           position = "dodge", 
           color = "black") + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 == "C"), 
           width = 15,
           color = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend", drop = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `scale_fill_discrete` breaks argument...

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", 
                              "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01")),
             col2 = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2), levels = c("C", "A", "B")),
             col3 = c(8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 5))


ggplot(df, aes(col1, col3, fill = col2)) + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 != "C"), 
           position = "dodge", 
           color = "black") + 
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(col2 == "C"), 
           width = 15,
           color = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("C", "A", "B"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>